# Resize current page to fit application height

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, pdfnet

is it possible to resize the current displayed page to fit the application height? I want to avoid the scrollbar on the right side to make my application a little more touch-friendlier.

I tried all the different [presentation modes](https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/html/T_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewWPF_PagePresentationMode.htm) but none of them seems to fit my needs.

Comment: you can have a look at ViewBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any vertical scroll bar you would want to use the FitPage zoom mode.
`pdfviewwpf.SetPageViewMode(PDFViewWPF.PageViewMode.e_fit_page);`

https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/?topic=html/M_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewWPF_SetPageViewMode.htm
https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/html/T_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewWPF_PageViewMode.htm

And you would also want to choose the single page presentation mode, or one of the other non-continuous page presentation modes.

https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/?topic=html/T_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewWPF_PagePresentationMode.htm

So here would be one example.

```
pdfviewwpf.SetPageViewMode(PDFViewWPF.PageViewMode.e_fit_page);
pdfviewwpf.SetPagePresentationMode(PDFViewWPF.PagePresentationMode.e_single_page);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ryan. It works just as expected!